# MYSQL Use 'is null' after 'on' and 'where' in 'left join' statement

Tags: mysql, sql, null, left-join

I would like to filter the highest person of each sex in user table, this is the code that works fine:

```
SELECT s1.name, s1.sex, s1.height 
FROM user s1 
LEFT JOIN user s2 ON s1.sex =s2.sex AND s1.height < s2.height 
WHERE s2.name IS NULL;
```

But this one won't work:

```
SELECT s1.name, s1.sex, s1.height 
FROM user s1 
LEFT JOIN user s2 ON s1.sex =s2.sex AND s1.height < s2.height AND s2.name IS NULL;
```

Is that mean 'is null' can only be used after 'where' clause?

Comment: Why do you need s2.name in the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Take a look on your second query, `s2.name` is not yet `NULL` because you are still joining the rows. Thus, the resulting value of the column can be evaluated as `null` or `null not` after it has been joined and can be filtered on the `where` clause.

Comment: Thanks, It is clear to me, Before joining  the table,there is no 'null' value in s2, 'null' is created after joining is complete, so it can be filtered with the 'where' clause.

Answer (score 3):

The first version is excluding the records that do not have a matching row in the `user` table -- these will have a `null` value when you join.

The second version is filtering records where the value in the `name` column is `null`.

- [Visual Explanation of Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)